# Prove the series $\sum_n \left(n \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})-\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\right)$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to prove the series $\sum ( n \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})-\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}))$ is convergent. How can this be done? I have tried the ratio test but it did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: yes the cosinus is in the summation

Answer (score 4):

Taylor expansions show:

$$n\ln (1+\frac{1}{n})-\cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt n})=\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{24n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{24}+o(1)\right)\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Thus, the terms are asymptotically proportional to $\frac{1}{n^2}$, whose sum is convergent. The comparison test gives us that this series is thus also convergent.